# What is the best way add all array item in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const arr1 = [
[{ id: 1 }],
[{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }], 
[{ id: 4 }]
];
```

I want to add all items in this array how can I do this. I want my output as Like:

```
const arr2 = [
     {id:1},
     {id:2},
     {id:3},
     {id:4}
   ]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays

Comment: @Jubayer simply using `arr1.flat()` will work for your example. If you have an array of even greater depth of nested arrays of objects, you can even use `arr1.flat(Infinity)` to flatten to a variable depth.

Comment: @Jubayer please take a look at my solution below when you have a chance

Answer (score 0):

Using `arr1.flat()` will work for your example. If you have an array of even greater depth of nested arrays of objects, you can even use `arr1.flat(Infinity)` to flatten to a variable depth:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 0 },
  [{ id: 1 }],
  [{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 }], 
  [{ id: 4 }]
];

console.log(arr1.flat());
```